I deleted the partition which had ubuntu
Hi so i recently switched from windows 10 to ubuntu with a very little knowledge of it....and then instead of fual booting i deleted windows and only has ubuntu left...first mistake i did that by creating partition in my ssd i didnt used any usb or dvd... Now there was a recent update in ubuntu and it was saying i have very little space left in that partition so i thought of deleting the partition and creating a new one but i deleted it and never created a new one..and just now as i restarted my laptop it didn't started and showing this error: no such partition Entering rescue mode grub rescue> This...pls help me to fix this i think i am cooked

Since you have deleted the Ubuntu-partition (and also Windows) you will have to install Ubuntu again. Just boot from the media you installed from last time, choose Install ...
